# Parent table width vs child td width

Tags: html

I have a table structure as below

```
<table width="100%">
<td width="18%"></td>
<td width="95%"></td>
</table>
```

The Actual table width is 100% but the child td's sum up to give 113%-Does this have any effect on the table layout??

Comment: Apparently yes; if you can't do maths properly your maths is ignored: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8as10ubj/). Also: you could have easily tested this yourself, is there a reason that you didn't? Or did your own tests produce conflicting data?

Comment: But i dont see the layout to be changed..can you tel me y?

Comment: This table is a child of another table which is 100% wide

Comment: is it possible that width attribute is not supported in latest versions of the browsers???

Comment: Test without the td width css in the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8as10ubj/2/ - apparently what happens is that the width of table stays at 100% of its parent, and the td's adjust   their width out of the respective proportion of the total width

Comment: does that mean whatever i have used is right

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is ENTIRELY dependent on the browser you are testing with. I'd strongly suggest not doing this if you want consistent results across multiple browsers and devices.

Comment: What can be the solution then?

Comment: That would depend on what you're trying to accomplish. Yes it has an affect on the layout. What are you trying to do? Create a table that is consistentlyl 13% larger than than the containing box or screen? Create cells that are larger than their containing table?